# Request AWS EC2 public images without CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working in an environment where the AWS CLI is not available and need to use the API using plain https, but having problems listing public AMIs by doing a GET of

```
https://ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeImages&Filter.1.Name=is-public&Filter.1.Value.1=true
```

This is very close to Example 2 in the official [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html#API_DescribeImages_Examples) but I receive the error:

```
<Code>UnknownParameter</Code>
<Message>The parameter Filter is not recognized</Message>
```

I don't think this could be signing/authentication problems as I get *AuthFailure* instead of *UnknownParameter* if I mess up authentication.

It feels like I'm looking at outdated documentation but I'm not able to find anything more current.

What kind of request can provide me with public AMIs?

Comment: Ignoring the error that was returned, you would also need to provide some authentication information to make the request. This can be quite complex. Have you considered using an AWS SDK, such as boto3 for Python? Also, what do you mean by "the AWS CLI is not available" -- can you install it?

Comment: I [sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) the request and just getting ?Action=DescribeImages without any filters will give me a non-error result. My code needs to run in a mobile context (Swift on iOS) without Python or a shell in which to install awscli.

Comment: [AWS SDK for Swift – Software Development Kit – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/)

Comment: This AWS SDK for Swift is in a prerelease stage and Amazon specifically warns against using it in production code. They also only support Cognito, DynamoDB, AIM and S3. I would need to create requests for listing AMIs myself leading right back to the original problem that I can't figure out how to filter AMIs from the API examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running awscli with the --debug flag I was able to determine how to compose requests. I was missing a Version parameter.

The following request will work if properly authenticated:

```
https://ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeImages&Version=2016-11-15&Filter.1.Name=is-public&Filter.1.Value.1=true
```